# Any one know why the time label in this app won't update every second ? any better idea to do this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple interface that shows current time BTC price, but the time doesn't update every second (it waits till the price update and that take 2 or 3 seconds) any idea on how to fix this?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time
import requests
import json

class App():

    def __init__(self):
     self.root = tk.Tk()
     self.root.title("Btc to USD")
     self.root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
     self.label1 = tk.Label(text="", padx=10, pady=10)
     self.label1.pack()
     self.label2 = tk.Label(text="", padx=10, pady=10)
     self.label2.pack()
     self.update()
     self.root.mainloop()

    def update_price(self):
     r1 = requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/site/headerdata.json", headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})
     r2 = requests.get("https://blockchain.info/ticker", headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})
     j1 = json.loads(r1.text)
     j2 = json.loads(r2.text)
     nowprice = "Coindesk : "+str(j1['bpi']['USD']['rate_float'])+" $\nBlockchain : "+str(j2['USD']['last'])+" $"
     self.label2.configure(text=nowprice,font=("Times",40,"bold italic"))
     self.root.after(1000, self.update_price)

    def update_time(self):
     self.label1.configure(text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),font=("Times",40,"bold"))
     self.root.after(1000, self.update_time)

    def update(self):
     self.update_time()
     self.update_price()

app=App()
```

Comment: Why is there **excessive** formatting on seemingly **random** words in your question **?** You may want to review [ask].

Comment: Your code works for me when I replace the code to do with `requests`. That is likely the issue.

Comment: `requests.get` blocks until finished, so it takes an indeterminate amount of time.

Comment: yeah that's why I tried to make 2 labels, and 2 different mthods (1 for time, and other for price) but as you see the same problem, how to fix that ? I mean separate the work

Comment: Seeing that you are updating them on the same interval have you tried putting all of it into one method? I would have all the request for label 2 ran first and then update label 2 with the data and then update label 1 with the time. This should fix the delay between the 2 updating.

Comment: I had try that, also I had try the time in the same label, but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use [asyncio](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/26/python-3-an-intro-to-asyncio/) so `update_price()` runs in a background thread.

Take care that you only have a limited number (e.g. 1) of BG downloads in progress at any instant.

Comment: tkinter doesn't work well in multiple threads. It works pretty good on some systems, not so well on others. It would be better to do `requests.get(...)` in another thread.

Comment: I think asyncio is just for python 3.4, I'm working with 2.7

Comment: Agreed that it makes more sense to have `update_price` do a non-blocking read from a `queue.Queue` and schedule a thread to run the request every second or two that pipes to that queue.